# Find position of given PK and next and previous row as one result row

Tags: mysql, sql

Table in question (striped unneeded cols):

```
car_id INT(11) PK
url VARCHAR(100)
signup TIMESTAMP
```

Default list query looks like:

```
SELECT car_id, url FROM car ORDER By signup DESC
```

Now i need to find the position of an car in the result set as it would be in the list query. AND the prev and next row's url.

I have tried many different approaches, and im finally not sure if its possible. (in one query).

Any help with the query or pointers to the right direction would be much appreciated.

**EDIT:**

the desired result would be:

```
pos, nextid, nexturl, previd, prevurl
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one -

+row position

```
SELECT car_id, url, signup, CONCAT(pos1, '/', @p1) position FROM (
  SELECT
    c.*,
    @p1:=@p1+1 pos1,
    @p2:=IF(car_id = 3 AND @p2 IS NULL, @p1, @p2)
  FROM
    cars c,
    (SELECT @p1:=0, @p2:=NULL) t
  ORDER BY
    signup
) t
WHERE
  pos1 BETWEEN @p2 - 1 AND @p2 + 1
```

---

You wrote:
*the desired result would be: pos, nextid, nexturl, previd, prevurl*

Try this query:

```
SELECT
  @p2 pos,
  MAX(IF(pos1 > @p2, car_id, NULL)) nextid,
  MAX(IF(pos1 > @p2, url, NULL)) nexturl,
  MAX(IF(pos1 < @p2, car_id, NULL)) previd,
  MAX(IF(pos1 < @p2, url, NULL)) prevurl
FROM (
  SELECT
    c.*,
    @p1:=@p1+1 pos1,
    @p2:=IF(car_id = 3 AND @p2 IS NULL, @p1, @p2)
  FROM
    cars c,
    (SELECT @p1:=0, @p2:=NULL) t
  ORDER BY
    signup
) t
WHERE
  pos1 BETWEEN @p2 - 1 AND @p2 + 1
```

Comment: the query itselfs works, but i dont get the position of the row only the row itself. its used for a navigation on the a page, to allow to browse through the pages. its shown as < 15 / 280 >. 15 would be the position of the row in the query from the question. next and prev rows you covered in your answer.

Comment: ...I saw your desired result. The query should be rewritten.

Answer (score 0):

```
(SELECT car_id, url FROM car WHERE car_id = ?)
UNION
(SELECT car_id, url FROM car WHERE signup >  (SELECT signup FROM car WHERE car_id = ?) ORDER By signup ASC LIMIT 1)
UNION
(SELECT car_id, url FROM car WHERE signup <  (SELECT signup FROM car WHERE car_id = ?) ORDER By signup DESC LIMIT 1)
```

Comment: doesnt find the position of given pk as it would be in the list query. but thanks for helping out anyway.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
  @previd AS previousid,
  @prevurl AS previousurl,
  @previd:=@id AS currentid,
  @prevurl:=@url AS currenturl,
  @id:=car_id AS nextid,
  @url:=url AS nexturl
FROM
  (SELECT @previd:=0) AS initprevid,
  (SELECT @prevurl:='') AS initprevurl,
  (SELECT @id:=0) AS initid,
  (SELECT @url:='') AS initurl,
  car
WHERE currentid=<whatever>
ORDER BY
  car.signup DESC
```

You can filter away the spurious currentid=0